# Texts being cut of plot - Matplotlib / Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting a simple boxplots  with the following code, but as can be seen in the result, some words are cut of the image. How can I solve this?

```
def generate_data_boxplots(data, ticks, x_axis_label, y_axis_label, file_path):
    """
    Plot multiple data boxplots in parallel
    :param data : a set of data to be plotted
    :param x_axis_label : the x axis label of the data
    :param y_axis_label : the y axis label of the data
    :param file_path : the path where the output will be save
    """
    plt.figure()
    bp = plt.boxplot(data, sym='r+')
    plt.xticks(numpy.arange(1, len(ticks)+1), ticks, rotation=15)
    plt.xlabel(x_axis_label)
    plt.ylabel(y_axis_label)

    # Overplot the sample averages, with horizontal alignment in the center of each box
    for i in range(len(data)):
        med = bp['medians'][i]
        plt.plot([numpy.average(med.get_xdata())], [numpy.average(data[i])], color='w', marker='s',
                 markeredgecolor='k')
    plt.savefig(file_path + '.png')
    plt.close()
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`plt.tight_layout()`](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/tight_layout_guide.html) to help reduce problems you have with text being cut off.

`plt.tight_layout()` will adjust subplot parameters to ensure that all objects fit inside the correct area.

Simply call `plt.tight_layout()` before `plt.show()` when generating your plots.

Answer (score 6):

use `fig.tight_layout` or pass some additional parameters to the `savefig` call.

```
def generate_data_boxplots(data, ticks, x_axis_label, y_axis_label, file_path):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    bp = ax.boxplot(data, sym='r+')
    plt.xticks(numpy.arange(1, len(ticks)+1), ticks, rotation=15)
    ax.set_xlabel(x_axis_label)
    ax.set_ylabel(y_axis_label)

    # Overplot the sample averages, with horizontal alignment in the center of each box
    for i in range(len(data)):
        med = bp['medians'][i]
        ax.plot([numpy.average(med.get_xdata())], [numpy.average(data[i])], color='w', marker='s',
                 markeredgecolor='k')
    fig.tight_layout()  # <----- this
    fig.savefig(file_path + '.png')
    fig.close()
```

or

```
def generate_data_boxplots(data, ticks, x_axis_label, y_axis_label, file_path):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    bp = ax.boxplot(data, sym='r+')
    plt.xticks(numpy.arange(1, len(ticks)+1), ticks, rotation=15)
    ax.set_xlabel(x_axis_label)
    ax.set_ylabel(y_axis_label)

    # Overplot the sample averages, with horizontal alignment in the center of each box
    for i in range(len(data)):
        med = bp['medians'][i]
        ax.plot([numpy.average(med.get_xdata())], [numpy.average(data[i])], color='w', marker='s',
                 markeredgecolor='k')
    fig.savefig(file_path + '.png', bbox_inches='tight')  # <------ this
    fig.close()
```